# How do I move a shape to the foreground or background in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a Code HS project in which I have to make a a few frames for a comic in Javascript. How do I make a shape appear on top of another shape (the intended background always covers up the characters)?

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML, set the CSS property "z-index" of the elements. The higher the z-index, more "on top" it is.

In Javascript you can manipulate the z-index at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript the css attributes is changed to camelCase

Like this:

```
  document.getElementById("img1").style.zIndex = "1";
```